# Definition of arclength parameter

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on this question that says that given any differentiable function $h(s)$, for $s\in(a,b)$, there is a planar curve for which $h(s)$ is the signed curvature function and $s$ is the arclength parameter.

I was able to find such curve, but my only question now is: what does it mean for $s$ to be the arclength parameter? I am not clear about the meaning of this. In the solution, they say

$$\int_a^s\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}ds = s-a$$

and so $s$ is the parameter. I mean I recognize the formula, it's the arclength computed at the value $s$. But now I don't get the conclusion. If someone can please clarify this to me I'd be extremely thankful!

Comment: I don't like any solution that uses $s$ both as a dummy variable of integration and as a limit of integration.

Answer (score 1):

All it means is that the speed of your parametrized curve is $1$. When you integrated the Frenet equations, you were assuming a parametrization by arclength.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a reparametrization of the curve such that it has the unit speed. For instance, $\gamma(x):I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a curve, in general, $|\gamma'(x)|\neq1$, in order to get the unit speed, we have to reparametrize our curve by a new parameters say $s$, now our curve become $\gamma(x(s)):[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and $|\gamma'(x)x'(s)|=1$.

An easy example is the circle with radius $r$. $(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)):[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is one of the parametrization; and $(r\cos(\theta/r),r\sin(\theta/r)):[0,2r\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is the parametrization by arclength. They are the same curve on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Topologically, $\gamma(x)$ and $\gamma(x(s))$ are the same curve, reparametrization doesn't change anything. But it can reduce the calculation in most situations

Comment: Is it enough to check that $\||\gamma'(s)||=1$? I mean, does $\||\gamma'(s)||=1$ imply that $\gamma$ is parametrized by arclength?

Comment: Exactly! look at the wekipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves